# StormPath Spring Boot Integration - getting secure HTTPS connection is required

Tags: java, nginx, spring-boot, https, stormpath

Trying to setup the production environment,  https connection gets terminated at the NGINX level. In order to accommodate this we have enabled the X-Forwarded-Proto and X-Forwarded-For HTTP Headers in the request.

Also applied code changes as indicated in this following link, 
https://shuaib.me/stormpath-ssl-termination/

Still receiving the error trying to access the stormpath built-in resources like https://<..>/oauth/token

{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "message": "A secure HTTPS connection is required for token requests - this is a requirement of the OAuth 2 specification."
}

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: What Stormpath SDK version are you using?  This should have been resolved in 1.1.0.

Comment: stormpath-default-spring-boot-starter 1.2.2

Answer (score 0):

What version of the Java SDK are you using?. The `X-Forwarded-Proto` header [is supported](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java/issues/139) out of the box since version `1.1.0`. If you are using that version (or newer) then there must be other problem; the more info you can provide the better. Thanks

Comment: So things should just work in that version. Can you re-try without applying the changes mentioned in that blogpost? What is the error you get? Any exception in the logs?

Comment: Removed the changes, I see following exception in the logs,.s.s.f.a.CookieAuthenticationResultSaver : INSECURE IDENTITY COOKIE RUNTIME: Your current Stormpath SDK cookie config doesn't allow insecure identity cookies (transmission over non-HTTPS connections)!

Comment: Good, take a look here: https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java/blob/master/extensions/servlet/src/main/java/com/stormpath/sdk/servlet/filter/account/CookieAuthenticationResultSaver.java#L173. As you can see there, we throw an exception because it is a configuration issue. You are not using HTTPs but you want the cookie to be secured. To solve this you can either set `stormpath.web.accessTokenCookie.secure` to `false` or make your web server to run with HTTPS.

Comment: Tried setting the stormpath.web.accessTokenCookie.secure to false , I don't get the above error in the logs , now I see only the warning INSECURE IDENTITY COOKIE CONFIGURATION: Your current Stormpath SDK account cookie configuration allows insecure identity cookies (transmission over non-HTTPS connections)!  However /oauth/token resource is still throwing the error secure HTTPS connection is required

Comment: Yeah, that is totally right. The cookie warning is letting you know that your app is not secure. That is not just fine, it is also a proper thing to do. WRT OAuth, if you want to use anything other than `localhost` you will need to enable HTTPS for your Application. This is documented in the [Login Section](https://docs.stormpath.com/java/spring-boot-web/login.html#security-notice) of our Spring Boot documentation. 

This allows you to develop on your local machine without requiring a TLS/SSL certificate, but will require one when you deploy to production.

Comment: Ok. our current infrastructure is setup so that the https connections gets terminated at NGINX level as follows.  client ---https--> NGNIX load balancer---http-->  Web Server.   We are under the impressing by using the X-Forwarded-Proto header at the NGINX level stormpath will issue the token. It looks like stormpath requires https connection all the way to the web server.  thanks!